# Type cast to different classes based on condition

Tags: c++

What do you do if you need such a thing?

Let us say, a function foo accepts a void*.

```
void foo(void* param);
```

Inside function definition of foo, based on a condition, it would be typecasted to either class ABC pointer or class DEF pointer. Something like this:

```
void foo(void* param) {
  if (condition) {
    ABC* abc = (ABC*) param;
  } else {
    DEF* abc = (DEF*) param;
  }

  // Irrespective of abc type, need to use abc quite a bit here. Such as abc->func1() etc.
  // So, abc should be made local to foo instead of the condition to use it later.
}
```

How do you solve this generically? Templates could be one way.

Comment: you didnt tell what is the problem you are trying to solve, only your current solution. Why does `foo` take a `void*` in the first place?

Comment: It looks like `ABC` and `DEF` should derive from common base class `XYZ` and `param` should be of type `XYZ*` (or better something that allows polymorphism and is not raw pointer). Class `XYZ` has method `func1()` (possibly pure virtual). Since you don't want to differentiate between `ABC` and `DEF`, then don't do that.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, Wrote it actually, Need to call functions such as abc->func1() after if/else condition.

Comment: you might want simple overloads. Possibly introducing a common base for `ABC` and `XYZ` so you can handle the common code

Comment: there would be no problem if `foo` would have two overloads instead of taking a `void*`. Why does it have to be `void*` ?

Comment: "Let us say, a function foo accepts a void*." the red alert should ring here already. This is your problem you need to fix, not doing wild casts inside the function and stuff. Fix `void*` and the "problem" you face now will be gone

Comment: maybe this will help to understand what I meant with "didnt tell the problem, only the solution" : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: to give you a proper answer you need to tell us what is the reason for `foo` taking a `void*` and maybe a bit about `ABC` and `XYZ`, why do you need one function to handle unrelated types? Or are they maybe related somehow?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, Thanks for your responses. Reason it takes void* is because it can accept two type of pointers. 

Call to foo function would be exactly like:

ABC* abc = new ABC();
foo(abc):

OR
DEF * def = new DEF();
foo(def);

This would be good in both the cases. Now inside the foo function, depending on the condition, I could typecast it back to either ABC* or DEF*.

Comment: Right now, your `abc` variable exists within the scope of your `if else` and will die afterwards. If you want it to live outside, it needs to have *one* type. So no, what you are trying to do won't work, but as the other guys already said, XY problem. I heavily suspect that your code should rather look like `void foo(BaseClass* pointer) { pointer->func(); }`.

Comment: you still dont explain why you want one function to accept two different types as parameter. Why dont you write a `foo(ABC*)` and a `foo(XYZ*)` ? If the two types are related, why cant you make them inherit from a common base class?

Comment: Please never use void* at all! If you have to deal with multiple different types use std::variant, if you have really no idea what type to handle, think about std::any. But if you "really" need std::any, rethink on your design. Have a function which do a cast and later on something on the casted type is a design failure! A function should never know of insides of a given type. That is not OOP.

Comment: You really seem to want inheritance here. Compiler is your friend, but it can only help if you actively work against it. Don't make your work harder by washing types away, especially when you need them back. You have a function, that expects one of two types. These types have a common function called `func1`. **This is _precisely_ the usecase for inheritance**. Unless you have a more detailed description of your actual **problem** (not solution), I'm voting to close this question as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of foo could be made in a way, that it is a pointer to a base class which has an integer for an interface type.

Cast the parameter to the base class pointer and you are able to get the interface type.

Then you can make it a `switch(interface_id)` or something like that.

*Warning: Code untested, just written from mind*

Example:

```
class Base_Class
{
  public:
  uint16_t interface_id=0;
}

class Derived_1 : public Base_Class
{
  public:
   Derived_1() : Base_Class(), interface_id(1)
   {

   }
}

class Derived_2 : public Base_Class
{
  public:
   Derived_2() : Base_Class(), interface_id(2)
   {

   }
}
```

now cast the parameter of foo to the base pointer:

```
void foo(void* param) {
 if (!param)
   return;
 Base_Class * b = static_cast<Base_Class*>(param);
 uint16_t interfaceID = b->interface_id;
 switch (interfaceID)
 {
   case 1:
     Dervided_1* c1 = static_cast<Derived_1*>(b); break;
   case 2:
   //...
 }
}
```

I use this method a lot when dealing with C APIs which are kinda fixed to use a void pointer (callbacks etc.). It may not be the smoothest way, but it seems to be easy to understand for quite a lot of people. This part makes it easy to maintain.

Other variants may be dynamic casting the base pointer and check the results. Or you can use virtual methods in the right way if you overwrite them in the derived classes.

Remember: if you have a void pointer, you are unable to perform a dynamic cast directly, so first cast to the base pointer, then perform the dynamic cast.

This is just a hint in the right direction, please do not use it as "copy and paste" answer

Comment: I can not think of a real use case where we have an externally stored id which gives us an idea of the type we cast to. There is always a good chance to cast to the wrong type which is always UB. Such strange design is a very bad idea I believe! having a const id inside the class itself is reimplementation of tagged union. And if it is a const there is no need to change id dynamically in constructor. See std::variant or use RTTI.

Comment: The answer is in the right direction, but has a few issues: (1) If possible (i.e. unless this is part of some fixed API), then it is better to define `foo()`to take a pointer to the `Base_Class` and define all operations needed by `foo()` as `virtual`. In most cases, this avoids the need to cast the pointer to a derived type. (2) *If* it is needed to cast the pointer, a `dynamic_cast` should be considered (3) Class variables (such as `interface_id`) cannot be `virtual`.

Comment: thank you @nielsen, I updated my answer. Based on the given code, I assumed the `void*` as parameter was fixed, update includes context to this case.

Comment: @MauriceRandomNumber You are correct this is what the OP asked (parameter needs to be `void *`). It just seems the OP needs a gentle introduction to polymorphism to be able to ask the right question. I think your answer is helpful from the starting point of the OP.